# How do I position a div relative to the parent div which contains dynamic text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on requirement where I need to show a popup message on click of some text (This is a dynamic text whose length can vary), am trying to achieve something as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

But the problem am facing is when I tr to position it if I change the text to something lengthy or short the popup still remains in the same place, I want it to be positioned with respect to the "*" irrespective of the text length (In this example: Ready within 4 hours)

**The HTML:**

```
 <div class="bopis-messaging">
   <a href="">Ready within 7 Days *</a>
     <div class="bopis-msg-content" data-layout="small">                        
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do e 
           iusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Utenim 
           ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
     </div>
</div>


    <style>
    .bopis-messaging {
       position: relative
    }
    .bopis-msg-content {
     width: 180px;
     border: 1px solid #333;
     position: absolute;
     right: 30%;
     top: -23%;
     height: auto;
     background: #ffffff;
     color: #333333;    
     font-family: Lato; 
     font-size: 12px;   
     line-height: 20px;
     padding: 16px;
   }
   </style>
```

[image]

It gave me this result, but if try to change the text to "Ready within 4 hours *" , the popup still stays in the same position, whereas i want it to be over the "*" .

[image]
Your help will be much appreciated

Comment: can you how do you generate the text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice approach would be to use data- attributes on your html, then display them via a pseudo-element content property.

```css
/*just for the SO snippet positioning*/
.bopis-messaging {
  margin: 140px;
}

/* stablishes that any anchor tag with a data-tooltip attibute
/* will be relative positioned, so the pseudo-element will be
/* absolute positioned accordingly*/
a[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
}

/* displays a tooltip as an absolute positioned pseudo-element, 
/* which contents are in the data-tooltip html attribute
/* starts as zero-scaled for a fancy display on hover*/
a[data-tooltip]::after {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #333333;    
  font-family: Lato; 
  font-size: 12px;   
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 16px;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin:bottom;
  transform: translate(50%, 0) scale(0);
  transition: transform 200ms ease-out;
}

/*reveals the tooltip on hover*/
a[data-tooltip]:hover::after {
  transform: translate(50%, 0) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="bopis-messaging">
   <a href="" data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do e iusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Utenim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud">Ready within 7 Days *</a>
   <br>
   <a href="" data-tooltip="shorter lorem ipsum is shorter">longer text is longer is longer is longer *</a>
   <br>
   <a href="" data-tooltip="shorter lorem ipsum is shorter">short text *</a>   
</div>
```

---

edit: Since you specified additional requirements, here's a version with a hiding div instead, as CSS pseudo-elements "content" will not parse HTML from a data-attibutes

```css
/*just for SO snippet positioning*/

.bopis-messaging {
  margin:170px;  
}

.bopis-hoverable{
  position:relative;
  display:inline;
}


/* displays a tooltip as an absolute positioned element, 
/* starts as zero-scaled for a fancy display on hover*/
.bopis-msg-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 230px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #333333;    
  font-family: Lato; 
  font-size: 12px;   
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin:bottom;
  transform: translate(50%, 0) scale(0);
  transition: transform 200ms ease-out;
}

/*reveals the tooltip on hover*/
.bopis-hoverable:hover > .bopis-msg-content{
  transform: translate(50%, 0) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="bopis-messaging">
   <div class="bopis-hoverable">
     <a href="#">Ready within 7 Days *</a>
     <div class="bopis-msg-content" data-layout="small">                        <h4>Ready within 7 Days</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur</strong> adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod <br> ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Utenim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</p>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I change the hover to click and will this still work?

Comment: sure, just need to change the :hover rule into a simple css class, and use javascript to toggle that class.

Comment: Can I make a part of the text inside the data-tooltip as bold and a break tag in it? Is that possible?

Comment: @MohammedJunaid not possible, since pseudo-selectors content taken from a data-attribute won't parse HTML tags. I've added an alternative with divs instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your "*" is always at the end of the text you can solve it like this:
(Se my comments in the css).

```html
<div class="container">
    <!--Just a bunch of br element to place the box further down the page. If not the popup wil go out of the screen. So this is a limitation of this solution-->
    <div class="bopis-messaging">
        <a href="">Ready within 7 Days *</a>
        <div class="bopis-msg-content" data-layout="small">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do e
            iusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Utenim
            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
        </div>
    </div>

</div>



<style>
    .bopis-messaging {
        margin-top: 300px; /*place the box further down the page. If not the popup wil go out of the screen. So this is a limitation of this solution*/
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block; /* Important so that the container will dynamically fit to the size of the content */
    }
    .bopis-msg-content {
        width: 180px;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        position: absolute;
        left: 100%; /*Place it at the end of the parent element */
        margin-left: -116px; /*half of width (this also includes the padding) to place the box back so its at the center of the "*" NB*/
        bottom: 200%; /*Place it above */
        height: auto;
        background: #ffffff;
        color: #333333;
        font-family: Lato;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 20px;
        padding: 16px;
    }

/*Added a triangle:*/
    .bopis-msg-content:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -10px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: solid 15px #000;
        border-left: solid 15px transparent;
        border-right: solid 15px transparent;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmhg90jd/) have a look.

```
<div class="bopis-messaging">
   <a href="">Ready within 4  Business Business Business Hours *</a>
     <div class="bopis-msg-content" data-layout="small">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, seddo eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Utenim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .bopis-messaging {
       position: relative;
       margin-top: 150px;
       display: inline-block;
    }
    .bopis-msg-content {
     width: 180px;
     border: 1px solid #333;
     position: absolute;
     right: -100px;
     bottom: 150%;
     height: auto;
     background: #ffffff;
     color: #333333;    
     font-family: Lato; 
     font-size: 12px;   
     line-height: 20px;
     padding: 16px;
   }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work , because the popup is just placed on the right of the text

Comment: Link Updated. Have a look

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.bopis-messaging {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.margin-top-200 {
    margin-top:200px;
}
.bopis-msg-content {
    width: 180px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="margin-top-200"></div>
<div class="bopis-messaging">
  <a href="">Ready within 7 Days *</a>
  <div class="bopis-msg-content" data-layout="small">                        
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do e 
    iusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Utenim 
    ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
  </div>
</div>
```